# How to send element id in argument of jquery upvote plugin function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

```
 var callback = function(data) {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/vote/',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                id: data.id,
                up: data.upvoted,
                down: data.downvoted,
                star: data.starred
            }
        });
    };

    $('.upvote').upvote({id: /how to send id of upvoted div here/, callback: callback});
```

and my django template code is:

```
    <div id="topic-{{object.id}}" class="upvote">
            <a class="upvote"></a>
            <span class="count">{{object.upvotes|sub:object.downvotes}}</span>
            <a class="downvote"></a>
            <a class="star"></a>
            </div>
```

I can extract the numerical part from id attribute of div. I just want to know how to send id in upvote function of ajax call.

I am using [Upvote](https://github.com/janosgyerik/upvotejs).

Comment: Got a link to the documentation of the plugin?

Comment: yep its the one mentioned by@ChrisHappy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send the id of the clicked `div` you can set the `data-id` attribute like this:

```
<div data-id="123">...</div>
```

If there is no such attribute in the dom, the value will be left undefined. So in your case you will want to set the div to be like this:

```
<div data-id="topic-{{object.id}}" class="upvote">
```

After `data-id` is set you can leave out `id` from the options object:

```
$('.upvote').upvote({callback: callback});
```

Comment: I can just do     `$(.upvote).attr("id")` to get the id and then extract numerical substring. My question is how to send the id in argument of upvote function.

Comment: the plugin docs say to use `data-id`, and the code sets default id to this: `id: jqdom.attr('data-id'),`

Comment: you can do `$(.upvote).attr("id")` but that won't give you which one you clicked on...

Comment: Thanks its working with simple tweak. In addition to adding the `data-id` attribute, I had to call `$('.upvote').upvote(callback:callback)` instead of `$('.upvote').upvote(id: somevalue, callback:callback)`. it was replacing data-id with someValue in latter case.

Comment: yup! yea by default it will look for `data-id` attribute, you can then override with options object, so best to leave it out: `$('.upvote').upvote({callback: callback});`